# Python : correct way to formulate try-except

Tags: python, scrapy, try-except

I'm scraping Tripadvisor with Scrapy ( https://www.tripadvisor.com/Hotel_Review-g189541-d15051151-Reviews-CitizenM_Copenhagen_Radhuspladsen-Copenhagen_Zealand.html ).

One of the items I scrape is attractions count and radius as well as the count and radius of the restaurants. This information is not always present ( https://www.tripadvisor.com/Hotel_Review-g189541-d292667-Reviews-Strandmotellet_Greve-Copenhagen_Zealand.html ). If it is not present I get this error message : "IndexError: list index out of range" ( https://pastebin.com/pphM8FSM)

I tried to write a try-error construction without any success:

```
try:
            nearby_restaurants0_attractions1_distance = response.css("._1aFljvmJ::text").extract()
except IndexError:
            nearby_restaurants0_attractions1_distance = [None,None]

items["hotel_nearby_restaurants_distance"] = nearby_restaurants0_attractions1_distance[1]
items["hotel_nearby_attractions_distance"] = nearby_restaurants0_attractions1_distance[2]
```

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 1):

List indices are zero-based, not one-based. If you are expecting a two-item list, you need to modify your last two lines to use `[0]` and `[1]` instead of `[1]` and `[2]`:

```
items["hotel_nearby_restaurants_distance"] = nearby_restaurants0_attractions1_distance[0]
items["hotel_nearby_attractions_distance"] = nearby_restaurants0_attractions1_distance[1]
```

I am not sure the IndexError was coming from when the data was missing, either. It might have just been hitting this bug even when the data was present. You may need to catch a different exception if the data is missing.

Comment: Hi Justin,

thank you for your answer. The list has indeed three items with "walking score" being the first one, which I didn't want to get. 

So the problem has to be somewhere else especially since it only occures in 3 out of about 90 Hotel sites I scrape ( those which just don't have walking- restaurant, and attraction score/amount). Do you have an idea for different exceptions that I could try ?

Comment: just found the solution !

Comment: It may also have worked to change `[None,None]` to `[None, None, None]`, if it is supposed to have 3 items in the list. Or, `[None] * 3` as a shortcut.

Answer (score 0):

Answer for everybody who is interested:

Scrapy searches for items in nearby_restaurants0_attractions1_distance but if nothing can be found it returns None. So there is no IndexError at that stage.

The IndexError occures later when items only fetches a part of the list - which is obviously not present when Scrapy returned a None-Object. [The pastebin also shows in a line above the IndexError that the problem was with items]

```
nearby_restaurants0_attractions1_distance = response.css("._1aFljvmJ::text").extract()
try:
    items["hotel_nearby_restaurants_distance"] = nearby_restaurants0_attractions1_distance[1]
except IndexError:
    items["hotel_nearby_restaurants_distance"] = None

try:
   items["hotel_nearby_attractions_distance"] = nearby_restaurants0_attractions1_distance[2]
except:
   items["hotel_nearby_attractions_distance"] = None
```